# Jquery transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

i have a problem at this page http://ncca.co/indust.php

i would like the "contents" area to appear on selection of the appropriate a href and then the black footer to sweep across from the left. when link is selected i would like the "contents" to disappear and the new one appear and the black bar to sweep to the right have a mild gap and the new black boarder sweep in from the left.

how can i accomplish this?

i dont know how to post the code

Comment: just copy & paste the code here, and press the codeblock button while highlighting your codes. Try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generically, what you will need to do is have a very wide div inside the "content" div which is set to overflow:hidden. Then you animate the offset of the x value to get the div you want into view.

```
<style>
    #container {
        width: 100px;
        overflow: none;
        position: relative;
    }

    #inner {
        width: 300%;
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
    }

    #container div {
        width: 100px;
        float: left;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <div id="inner">
        <div>Foo</div>
        <div>Bar</div>
        <div>Baz</div>
    </div>
</div>
<a id="show_1">Link 1</a>
<a id="show_2">Link 2</a>
<a id="show_3">Link 3</a>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#show_1").click(function(){
            $("#inner").animate(
                {"left": 0}
                1000 // Animate for 1 second
            );
        });

        $("#show_2").click(function(){
            $("#inner").animate(
                {"left": 100}
                1000 // Animate for 1 second
            );
        });

        $("#show_3").click(function(){
            $("#inner").animate(
                {"left": 200}
                1000 // Animate for 1 second
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Docs on animate here: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Live example here: http://www.volunteerspot.com/Organizer/Register

Hope that points you in the right direction!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jester12345/mNb7V/ - set up this example on JS Fiddle, and fixed a couple of code errors... that I don't seem to be able to edit above.